# Creating CSS overlay prevent clicking underneath in IE

Tags: css

I am trying to create an overlay that will display in IE < 9 and display a message about upgrading the browser.  The overlay and message are showing up fine.  They only thing I can't figure out is how to prevent the elements on the page from still being clickable.  This is the relevant HTML and CSS.

HTML:

```
 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/blockIE.css")" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="blockIE"><div class="blockIEMessage"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/no-ie6.png")" alt='' style='float: left;'/><p><br /><strong>Sorry! This page doesn't support your browser.  Your browser is out of date and insecure.</strong><br /><br />Please upgrade your browser to <a href="http://firefox.com">Mozilla Firefox</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blockIE
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background:transparent;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50000000,endColorstr=#50000000); 
    zoom: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.blockIEMessage 
{
    background-color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6000;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Comment: @cimmanon For your average website I  would agree with you, but if the primary functionality of the site involves technology that older IE browsers can't support such as a HTML canvas then it would be a perfectly valid move.

Comment: Regardless if I should or shouldn't do this, does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: @dmikester1 you can click the content under the message? http://jsfiddle.net/uQ7FN/

Comment: @cimmanon I assume you are talking about corporations running XP that won't let their users dl Firefox or Chrome?  This site likely won't be used by those types of people.

Comment: @marcel that link works exactly like I would expect it to.  But for some reason, my page is not doing that.

Comment: @marcel take that back, it works fine in Firefox, but when I try in IE6, it appears that jsfiddle does not work at all in IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just hiding all links, buttons, inputs, etc when the overlay shows up so the user won't be able to click any of them when the overlay is showing.  I don't think this is a mean move at all.  If users are stuck on XP and IE8 they can upgrade to Firefox or Chrome.  I'm not going to waste hours getting this site to work in old IE.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper around your page content, place the blockIEMessage outside the wrapper and set it to `.wrapper{display:none}` for IE<8.

Alternately position a transparent box above your page content, then place your blockIEMEssage above that:

```
 .transparent-box{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     position:fixed;
     zoom: 1;
     filter: alpha(opacity=50);
     opacity: 0.5;
     z-index:10;
 }

 .blockIEMessage{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:20;
}
```

center your message in a div inside the .blockIEMessage. and set your opacity to your liking.

Comment: Problem is I like having the content show through the overlay so the user has a better idea about what is happening.

Comment: @dmkister1 , you should understand that you just need to turn `position:absolute` to `fixed` in `.blockIE` . answer should be updated : http://jsfiddle.net/uQ7FN/2/

Comment: when I change position to fixed, no content behind shows up in IE6